# Custom 401 page with authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest failure - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest method with rails 4, to let an admin sign in and perform some simple tasks. All links and sources at the bottom.

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :authenticate, only: :index # etc

def authenticate
   authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest(CONFIG[:realm]) do |username|
     session[:admin] = username
     USERS[username]
   end
 end
```

This works as expected, however the default 401 page rendered when a user cancels the login process is terrible, it is a blank page with some text. I am using custom error templates as seen in Railscasts.com EP#53 and it would be great if I can use the same convention for this 401 error.

Is there a way to either amend the method below so displays a custom 401 page (Preferably without including all of the controller view and url helpers) or a simpler way altogether to achieve a dynamic 401 page?

```
ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Digest.module_eval do
  def authentication_request(controller, realm, message = nil)
    message ||= "You are unauthorized to access this page.\n"
    authentication_header(controller, realm)
    controller.response_body = message
    controller.status = 401
  end
end
```

**Sources**

`Railscasts EP#53` Custom error templates: http://railscasts.com/episodes/53-handling-exceptions-revised -

`authenticate_request` method which seems to govern the 401 handling, source be seen in full at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04cda1848cb847c2bdad0bfc12160dc8d5547775/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L244

`authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest` method and example can be seen here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Digest.html#method-i-authentication_request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this great blog post about the subject the following code renders the errors/401 template gracefully. (Preferably clean up to use super rather than the deprecated alias_chaining method)

config/initializers/authentication.rb

```
ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Digest.module_eval do
  def authentication_request_with_customization(controller, realm, message = nil)
    message = controller.render_to_string(template: "errors/401")
    authentication_request_without_customization(controller, realm, message)
  end
  alias_method_chain :authentication_request, :customization
end
```

Original post: http://p373.net/2013/11/16/how-to-customize-http-digest-authentication-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails/